# How can I get the path to a folder using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

So right now I'm trying to make my app find the path of a folder to then look for a txt file inside of it.

I have done it before by using the path name, but what I really need is to find that path automatically. Here is some code of how I was doing it before:

```
var file = File("/storage/emulated/0/IS4-PDF-RDP/").walk().find { it.extension == "txt"}
```

And here is the code I came up trying to get the path:

```
val path = context.filesDir.absolutePath
var file = File("$path/").walk().find { it.extension == "txt"}
```

Comment: It's unclear what kind of path you're looking for. `filesDir` from `Context` will return the path to the private `files` directory of your app's data directory, which is invisible to the user. So in case you want to find a file in the user's visible area (which is also managed by your app), check `context.externalFilesDir`

Comment: I'm still a beginner using kotlin so I still don't understand some of the things like `context` but basically I want the app to find the path to the folder "IS4-PDF-RDP" which will be located somewhere on the internal storage of the phone.

Comment: I think you're really close. Might be wrong since I'm going off memory. `var file = context.filesDir.walk().find{i.extension == "txt"}`

Comment: You will need to read up on the different types of file spaces on Android. On Android you typically don't work with absolute paths.